# Keras model.fit runs out of memory in Google Colab Pro

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying out a simple sequential model with the below dataset.
Using Colab PRO with 35 GB RAM + 225 GB Disk space.

1. Total sentences - 59000
2. Total words - 160000
3. Padded seq length - 38

So train_x (59000,37), train_y (59000)

I'm using FastText for embedding layer. FastText model generated weights with
(rows) vocab_size 113000
(columns/dimentionality) embedding_size 8815

Here is how the model.summary() looks like

[image]

It takes about ~15 mins to compile the model but .fit crashes without adequate memory.

I've brought down the batch_size to 4 (vs 32 default).. still no luck.

epochs=2
verbose=0
batch_size=4

history = seq_model.fit(train_x,train_y, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose,callbacks=[csv_logger],batch_size=batch_size)

Appreciate any ideas to make this work.

Comment: This is not a simple sequential model, your model was 1498 Million parameters, it is extremely big, for comparison ResNet has 2 million parameters, and VGG around 150 million. Training such a big model requires some engineering challenges, so you should maybe rethink if this is what you want to do.

Comment: The weights take ~6 Gb. I think you have a chance to train with simple optimizer and batch_size of 1. But training of such a huge model may take years unless you have a big number of TPUs

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy - thanks for the feedback.Any suggestions to rethink?

Answer (score 1):

If what I am seeing is right, your model is simply too large!
It has almost 1.5 billion parameters. That's way too much.
Reducing the batch size will not help at all.